# write concern DeprecationWarning when using mongoengine in django

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine in a python django project of mine.

The django version is: 1.5.1

mongoengine version is: 0.7.10 (latest version retrieved by pip install)

I get the following warning upon insertion of documents to the mongo db:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:592: DeprecationWarning: The safe parameter is deprecated. Please use write concern options instead.
```

How do I fix this warning on the mongoengine version I'm using? The only documentation I can find is for later versions.

Comment: Please see http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a warning from pymongo and can be ignored.

The next version of MongoEngine 0.8 now uses the `MongoClient` and will be released this week.

Comment: Thanks, mongoengine 0.8 fixes this warning.